# Can a file descriptor be duplicated multiple times?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, file-descriptor

I've been looking for quite a while and cannot find the answer to my question.

I'm trying to reproduce a shell in C, with full redirections. In order to do this, I wanted to open the file before executing my command.

For example, in `ls > file1 > file2`, I use `dup2(file1_fd, 1)` and `dup2(file2_fd, 1)` and then I execute `ls` to fill the files, but it seems a standard output can only be open once so only `file2` will be filled, because it was the last one to be duplicated.

Is there a way to redirect standard output to multiple file?

Is there something I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: As many times as you don't strike a process limit imposed to your account by the system administrator.  There's a limit on the amount of open files that you cannot ignore.  This question is not about programming, but about unix internal workings.  Despite of this I'll not vote for it to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is the exact reason why the `tee` command exists (you can take a look at its source code [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c)).

You cannot duplicate a file descriptor using `dup2()` multiple times. As you already saw, the last one overwrites any previous duplication. Therefore you cannot redirect the output of a program to multiple files directly using `dup2()`.

In order to do this, you really need multiple descriptors, and therefore you would have to open both files, launch the command using `popen()` and then read from the pipe and write to both files.

Here is a very simple example of how you could do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 4096

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *pipe;

    fp1 = fopen("out1.txt", "w");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        perror("fopen out1 failed");
        return 1;
    }

    fp2 = fopen("out2.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        perror("fopen out2 failed");
        return 1;
    }

    // Run `ls -l` just as an example.
    pipe = popen("ls -l", "r");

    if (pipe == NULL) {
        perror("popen failed");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t nread, nwrote;
    char buf[N];

    while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, N, pipe))) {
        nwrote = 0;
        while (nwrote < nread)
            nwrote += fwrite(buf + nwrote, 1, nread - nwrote, fp1);

        nwrote = 0;
        while (nwrote < nread)
            nwrote += fwrite(buf + nwrote, 1, nread - nwrote, fp2);
    }

    pclose(pipe);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is only to give a rough estimate on how the whole thing works, it doesn't check for some errors on `fread`, `fwrite`, etc: you should of course check for errors in your final program.

It's also easy to see how this could be extended to support an arbitrary number of output files (just using an array of `FILE *`).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to redirect standard output to multiple files?

Many file descriptors cannot be made one file descriptor. You need to write into each file descriptor separately. This is what `tee` utility does for you.

Comment: Thank's ! I'll definitely do that !

Comment: But that doesn't mean redirection.  Redirection is when you don't know where that descriptor came from.  Redirection is indeed a convention, you always receive three already open descriptors, but nothing impedes you to receive 5 (as ms-dos does) or none at all (just `close(2)` them before calling `exec(2)`)  `tee(1)` needs a file name to open it and write, so it knows (and opens) what file it is writing to.

Answer (score 1):

Standard output is not different from any other open file, the only special characteristic is for it to be file descriptor `1` (so only one file descriptor with index 1 can be in your process)  You can `dup(2)` file descriptor `1` to get, let´s say file descriptor `6`.  That's the mission of `dup()` just to get another file descriptor (with a different number) than the one you use as source, **but for the same source**.  Dupped descriptors allow you to use any of the dupped descriptors indifferently to output, or to change open flags like *close on exec* flag or *non block* or *append* flag (not all are shared, I'm not sure which ones can be changed without affecting the others in a dup).  They share the file pointer, so every `write()` you attempt to any of the file descriptors will be updated in the others.

But the idea of redirection is not that.  A convention in unix says that every program will receive three descriptors **already open** from its parent process.  So to use forking, first you need to consider how to write notation to express that a program will receive (already opened) more than one output stream (so you can redirect any of them properly, *before calling the program*)  The same also applies for joining streams.  Here, the problem is more complex, as you'll need to express how the data flows might be merged into one, and this makes the merging problem, problem dependant.

*File `dup()`ping is not a way to make a file descriptor to write in two files... but the reverse, it is a way to make **two different file descriptors to reference the same file**.*

The only way to do what you want is to duplicate `write(2)` calls on every file descriptor you are going to use.

As some answer has commented, `tee(1)` command allows you to fork the flow of data in a pipe, but not with file descriptors, `tee(1)` just opens a file, and `write(2)`s there all the input, in addition to write(2)`ing it to stdout also.

There's no provision to fork data flows in the shell, as there's no provision to join (in paralell) dataflows on input.  I think this is some abandoned idea in the shell design by Steve Bourne, and you'll probably get to the same point.

BTW, just study the possibility of using the general `dup2()` operator, which is <*n*`>&`*m*>, but again, consider that, for the redirecting program, `2>&3 2>&4 2>&5 2>&6` mean that you have pre-opened 7 file descriptors, `0`...`6` in which `stderr` is an alias of descpritors `3` to `6` (so any data written to any of those descriptors will appear into what was `stderr`) or you can use `2<file_a 3<file_b 4<file_c` meaning your program will be executed with file descriptor `2` (stderr) redirected from `file_a`, and file descriptors `3` and `4` *already open* from files `file_b` and `file_c`.  Probably, some notation should be designed (and it doesn't come easily to my mind now, how to devise it) to allow for piping (with the `pipe(2)` system call) between different processes that have been launched to do some task, but you need to build a general graph to allow for generality.